# Java documentation that is searchable like iPhone Obj-C Documentation?

Tags: java, documentation

Is there a Java SE 6 documentation that is searchable like Apple's built-in Xcode documentation?

I suppose Google could be used to search the website that the Java 6 documentation is hosted on but I'd prefer a nice app or website where I can just search for the things I want.

Or I could even just CTRL-F to find it on the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows, these [javadocs compiled into CHM format](http://www.allimant.org/javadoc/index.php) are great.

Switch to 'index' tab, and start typing text in textfield ... you'll immediatelly see the list of matching classes/methods.

Comment: 54 mb O.O pretty large but thanks! for Mac, iChm should work. Am testing now.

Answer (score 1):

I wont recommend a search for Sun JavaDocs only. Searching in Google for some functionality returns results from everywhere. Including Apache Commons and lots of other useful open source libraries.

Finding a functionality in an open source library is better than reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/  In particular look at the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) and click on the "Index" near the top.

Comment: searchbox is still quicker :\

Comment: True. Javadoc was pretty revolutionary when it came out.  It would be *great* if someone could upgrade it with an AJAX API, Lucene text search, and so on.